# How to draw quotes on an image in android

Tags: android, object, draw

I want to create an Object that can be draw on an Image when I touch on a point of the image.
In particular I have a class ImageView that implements View, I have defined onTouchEvent on ImageView, but know I want to create an Object to be drawn on the ImageView (everytime a touch on a point I want to create and draw this Object on the point I have touched).
How can I do this?
This is what I have done:

```
public class ViewImage extends View {

private float startX, startY;
private float endX, endY;
private float middleX, middleY;
static public Paint p;
private float dist = 20;
private float startYp, startXp, startYn, startXn;
private float endYp, endXp, endYn, endXn;
private static final float halfHeight = 20;
private static final float halfWidth = 20;
private RectF startArea, endArea, middleArea;
private boolean isLock;
private double distance;
Ruler rul;


private final double PIXEL_ON_METER_RATIO = 100; // Known value from
                                                    // measurer

public ViewImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
    p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    setLock(false);
    rul=new Ruler(this.getContext());
}

public ViewImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    setLock(false);
    rul=new Ruler(this.getContext());
}

@SuppressLint({ "DrawAllocation", "WrongCall" })
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(startX,startY,halfHeight,p);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x=event.getX();
    float y=event.getY();
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        startX = event.getX();
        startY = event.getY();
    }
    // manage touch input
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        rul.setStartX(x);
        rul.setStartY(y);
    }
    if (!rul.isLock()){
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (!rul.getEndArea().contains(x, y) && !rul.getMiddleArea().contains(x, y)) {
            rul.setStartX(event.getX());
            rul.setStartY(event.getY());
        }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (rul.getStartArea().contains(x, y)) {
            rul.setStartX(event.getX());
            rul.setStartY(event.getY());
        } else {

            // case for rigid traslation
            if (rul.getMiddleArea().contains(x, y)) {
                rul.setStartX(getStartX()+x-middleX);
                rul.setStartY(getStartY()+y-middleY);
                rul.setEndX(getEndX()+x-middleX);
                rul.setEndY(getEndY()+x-middleY);
            } else {
                rul.setEndX(event.getX());
                rul.setEndY(event.getY());
            }
        }
        invalidate();
    }}
    else
    {

    }
    rul.setDistance();
    MeasureActivity.message.setText(Double.toString(distance)
            + "centimetri");
    return true;
}
```

---

```
public class Ruler extends View {

private boolean isLock;
private float startX, startY;
private float endX, endY;
private float middleX, middleY;
static public Paint p;
private float dist = 20;
private float startYp, startXp, startYn, startXn;
private float endYp, endXp, endYn, endXn;
private static final float halfHeight = 20;
private static final float halfWidth = 20;
private RectF startArea, endArea, middleArea;
private double distance;

private final double PIXEL_ON_METER_RATIO = 100; // Known value from
                                                    // measurer
public Ruler(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setLock(false);
}

public Ruler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setLock(false);
}

@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // define areas sensitive to touch
    startArea = new RectF(startX - halfWidth * 3, startY - halfHeight * 3,
            startX + halfWidth * 3, startY + halfHeight * 3);
    endArea = new RectF(endX - halfWidth * 3, endY - halfHeight * 3, endX
            + halfWidth * 3, endY + halfHeight * 3);
    middleX = (endX + startX) / 2;
    middleY = (endY + startY) / 2;
    middleArea = new RectF(middleX - halfWidth * 3, middleY - halfHeight
            * 3, middleX + halfWidth * 3, middleY + halfHeight * 3);
    // ugly things to draw perpendicular lines
    double slope = (endY - startY) / (endX - startX);
    double perpendicular = -1 / slope;
    // to find point at a fixed distance, on the perpendicular. Maybe better
    // to semplify
    startYp = (float) (startY + Math
            .sqrt((Math.pow(dist * perpendicular, 2) / (1 + Math.pow(
                    perpendicular, 2)))));
    startXp = (float) (startX + (startYp - startY) / perpendicular);
    // to find opposite respect startX,startY
    startYn = 2 * startY - startYp;
    startXn = 2 * startX - startXp;
    // the same code as above
    endYp = (float) (endY + Math
            .sqrt((Math.pow(dist * perpendicular, 2) / (1 + Math.pow(
                    perpendicular, 2)))));
    endXp = (float) (endX + (endYp - endY) / perpendicular);
    endYn = 2 * endY - endYp;
    endXn = 2 * endX - endXp;
    // draw the measurer
    canvas.drawLine(startXp, startYp, startXn, startYn, p);
    canvas.drawLine(endXp, endYp, endXn, endYn, p);
    canvas.drawCircle(middleX, middleY, halfWidth / 10, p);
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, p);
    canvas.drawText(distance + " cm", middleX, middleY, p);
    p.setTextSize(30);
    canvas.drawCircle(200, 150, halfHeight, p);
}

public void setLock(boolean lockState) {
    isLock = lockState;
    if (isLock)
        ViewImage.p.setColor(Color.RED);
    else
        ViewImage.p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}

public boolean isLock(){
    return isLock;
}

public void setStartX(float aStartX) {
    startX = aStartX;
}

public void setStartY(float aStartY) {
    startY = aStartY;
}

public void setEndX(float endX) {
    this.endX = endX;
}

public void setEndY(float endY) {
    this.endY = endY;
}

public void setDistance(){
    double pixelDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(startX - endX, 2)
            + Math.pow(startY - endY, 2));
    distance = pixelDistance / PIXEL_ON_METER_RATIO;
    distance = Math.floor(distance * 1000) / 100; // troncamento alla
                                                    // seconda decimale
}

public float getStartX() {
    return startX;
}

public float getStartY() {
    return startY;
}

public float getEndX() {
    return endX;
}

public float getEndY() {
    return endY;
}

public RectF getStartArea(){
    return startArea;
}
public RectF getEndArea(){
    return endArea;
}
public RectF getMiddleArea(){
    return middleArea;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw your image in `canvas` and you have direct method `canvas.drawBitmap()` to do that.

As you know the point of touch you can `draw` the object above your image in `canvas` itself.